# there is the/a/this - are all valid?

Tags: meaning

> 1 There is **the** word "Hello". Have you heard it before?
>
> 2 There is **a** word "Hello". Have you heard it before?
>
> 3 There is **this** word "Hello". Have you heard it before?

Are all three wrong? I thin that 1 is wrong for sure but can you explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. "There is the word XXX" could assume that the listener knows the word and you are using it as an example.
2. "There is a word XXX" assumes that the listener doesn't already know it.
3. Using *this* as a substitute for an article ("I met this girl") is colloquial, and frowned on by some. It's OK if you are using *this* in its proper sense - the word is written down and you are pointing to it.